# I need help to delete an image from folder when the record is deleted from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that stores image name in the table and the file in a folder on the server. What i want to do is to be able to delete the record from the database and at the same time, delete the corresponding image which has its name in the table record, from the folder on the server. Any help would be greatly appreciated Below is the code:

```
if ((isset($_POST['hiddenFieldID'])) && ($_POST['hiddenFieldID'] != "")) {
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM photodiary WHERE pdiaryID=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['hiddenFieldID'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_connMain, $connMain);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $connMain) or die(mysql_error());

  $deleteGoTo = "adphotodiary.php?user=" . $row_rsadmin['adID'] . "";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to all who helped. Sorry i did not update this earlier but i solved the problem. Of course, with everyone's help and some further reading. 
What i did was to first define the target, then got the id of the field to be deleted from the browser request, ran a query to select the field record from the database based on the id, then used the unlink function in php to unlink the image from the target folder initially defined. 
After this, then proceeded to delete the record from the table.

Below is the code.

```
$target = "../photodiary/";

if ((isset($_POST['hiddenFieldID'])) && ($_POST['hiddenFieldID'] != "")) {

    $imID = $_GET['pdid'];
            $query_pd  = "SELECT photo FROM photodiary WHERE pdiaryID = $imID";     
            $resulttt = mysql_query($query_pd) or die('Error, get image info failed. ' . mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resulttt);

            if(($row['photo']) != "")
            {
                unlink($target . $row['photo']);
            }

  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM photodiary WHERE pdiaryID=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['hiddenFieldID'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_connMain, $connMain);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $connMain) or die(mysql_error());

  $deleteGoTo = "confirm_del.php?user=" . $row_rsadmin['aID'] . "";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're gonna have to do a SELECT query to get the filename and retrieve its path on the server. Then you can send the DELETE query, and if it succeeds, you'll delete the file.

```
if ((isset($_POST['hiddenFieldID'])) && ($_POST['hiddenFieldID'] != "")) {
  $getPathSql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM photodiary WHERE pdiaryID=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['hiddenFieldID'], "int"));
  mysql_select_db($database_connMain, $connMain);
  $pathResult = mysql_query($getPathSql , $connMain) or die(mysql_error());
  $path = ...
  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM photodiary WHERE pdiaryID=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['hiddenFieldID'], "int"));

  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $connMain) or die(mysql_error());
  if($Result1 && is_file($path)) unlink($path);

  $deleteGoTo = "adphotodiary.php?user=" . $row_rsadmin['adID'] . "";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}
```

Comment: And I really hope the path data in the database didn't come from user input...  http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @Armel: tried but not deleting image in folder. folder path is:- $path = "../photodiary/";

Answer (score 1):

You can use [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) to delete files with php. If you pass it the location of the file it will remove it for you provided that php has the correct permissions in the directory that the file is located(see [chmod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) for permissions).

So after you have deleted the file from your database (do a check to make sure the record has been removed) you would then proceed to call unlink on the location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [unlink($pathtofile)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) php function

Answer (score -1):

u can use unlink... for example

```
unlink('pathtofile');
```